# laravel storage folder converted into files while uploading on server

Tags: laravel

I am working on laravel 5.4. I have used laravel storage where I have uploded images. It works fine in local. But when I have created zip and uploaded it on server then the **public/storage** folder is damaged and converted into **files**. That's why images are not visible on website.

Then what I have do to resolve it. I have delete that files and created zip of storage folder and upload it on server. And unzip that folder then images are visible.

Now, I am facing the another issue. Images are not uploaded into the storage folder.

So how to prevent this issue?

Comment: Please give us some codes! or samples or anything more clear

Comment: @MisaGH Its not for the code. Its about the link storage folder.

Comment: I don't get the `converted into files` and `damaged`. You should explain more.

Comment: Also, Is your storage folder writable?

Comment: @MisaGH yes, its a writable.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for it. I have used putty to use terminal of server.

First I have deleted storage folder from the public directory. Secondly, I had open directory of project folder in terminal using putty. Then write command as below :

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Now, its working perfect. As well as it restore all the images.